# Android/Java - How to detect whether an emoji/emoticon is present in the string?

Tags: android, mysql, unicode, emoji, emoticons

I'm building a chat application in which I'll be using emoticons, so the problem is that when I enter and send the text, for eg. - 
"Hahha this is so funny "
In MySQL, it gets saved as "Hahha this is so funny ??"

Can anyone tell me how to detect whether the string being saved to server contains an emoji and if it does, then accordingly convert the emoji part to special unicode format?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: You _will_ need `utf8mb4`, not just `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like this to decode the text first. 
I have't tried it myself but from what I see, it is possible.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1806